# Hola como puedo hacer que javascript detecte si cambio la resolución?

Tags: javascript, css3

estoy intentando hacer un menú adaptable, pero al cambiar la resolución no sé cómo quitar el estilo, o como hacer que por java detecte que se cambió la resolución de pantalla y quite la clase desplegar y el estilo display:block  .
código en javascript;

```
const btnMenu = document.querySelector("#btnMenu");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
btnMenu.addEventListener("click",function(){
    menu.classList.toggle("mostrar");
});    
const subMenuBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".submenu-btn");
for(let i=0; i < subMenuBtn.length; i++){
    subMenuBtn[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 1020){
            const subMenu = this.nextElementSibling;
            if(subMenu.classList.contains("desplegar")){
                subMenu.classList.remove("desplegar");
                subMenu.removeAttribute("style");    
            }else{
                subMenu.classList.add("desplegar");
                subMenu.style.display ="block";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[image: como se ve en la imagen al presionar usuario al submenú se le agrega la clase desplegar y el estilo para ver los submenú]

[image: y en la segunda imagen amplié la resolución y sigue la clase y el estilo como puedo hacer que se quite automáticamente al cambiar la resolución]

Comment: Java !== Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi

```js
function viewport_set(){
 console.log(screen.width)
 console.log(screen.height)
}

window.onresize = function() { 
  viewport_set(); 
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias con esa función ya funciona como quiero

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la siguiente sentencia:

```
if (screen.width < 1020){
   //...
}
```

Recuerda que el objeto screen dependerá del objeto window. Más información [aquí](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/detectar-resolucion-pantalla-usuario-javascript.html).

Comment: lo intente pero de esta forma solo se desplegaba el submenú si cambiaba a modo táctil o de celular pero si achicaba la pantalla en normal no hacia nada y el estilo igual no se iba, igual muchas gracias por la respuesta ya pude solucionar el problema